# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

I keep on getting the TypeError Error when ever I start my application, but only one of the Error's is in my Actual app.js file. The rest are in express's files. My code:

```js
function checkHttps(req, res, next){
  // protocol check, if http, redirect to https
  
  if(req.get('X-Forwarded-Proto').indexOf("https")!=-1){
    return next()
  } else {
    res.redirect('https://' + req.hostname + req.url);
  }
}
```

But the rest of the files I have no control over.. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the protocol you can go with `req.protocol`.

If `X-Forwarded-Proto` is a header, you need to go with

```
req.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Proto').indexOf("https")!=-1
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but now it's saying "req.headers.get" isn't a function.

Comment: Please, try `req.headers['X-Forwarded-Proto']`